# Two different outputs from the same function on php and javascript

Tags: javascript, php, hash

I have a function `djb2` on php and javascript,
php

```
function hash_djb2($str){
$hash = 5381;
$length = strlen($str);
for($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) {
    $hash = (($hash << 5) + $hash) + $str[$i];
}
return $hash;
}
```

and javascript

```
djb2Code = function(str){
var hash = 5381;
for (i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
    char = str.charCodeAt(i);
    hash = ((hash << 5) + hash) + char; /* hash * 33 + c */
}
return hash;
}
```

on php I call

```
hash_djb2("123456789egrdhfdtjdtjdtjrt");
```

and the output is

> -4235984878

and in javascript I call

```
djb2Code("123456789egrdhfdtjdtjdtjrt");
```

and the output is

> 27338942

Why is that and how can I fix it?

Thank you

Comment: and which one is correct ?? and usually is good to avoid doing same things on two sides

Comment: I dont know haha, but I dont care I just need them buth to do the same thing

Comment: Those are not the same function. Your PHP uses `$str[$i]`, which is a **character**. whilst your javascript function uses `char.charCodeAt(i)` which returns **integer**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those are not the same functions. Your PHP uses `$str[$i]`, which is a **character**. Your JavaScript function uses `char.charCodeAt(i)` which returns **integer**.

Change your PHP function like this ...

```
function hash_djb2($str){
    $hash = 5381;
    $length = strlen($str);
    for($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) {
        $char = ord($str[$i]);                     // this line is added
        $hash = (($hash << 5) + $hash) + $char;    // this line is modified
    }
    return $hash;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to use [ord](http://php.net/ord%E2%80%8E) in php code

```
hash = (($hash << 5) + $hash) + ord($str[$i]);
```